# Strange CSS class used in email signature template

Tags: html, css, email, outlook, signature

I am debugging email signature issues in Outlook for Mac (v16.34) and I have come across css classes that are used that I've never seen before and don't seem to reference anything directly:

```
class="sc-jDwBTQ dWtMUn"
```

I pulled a signature template off github: https://github.com/shiweifong/lethoe/blob/master/signature-june.html

If anyone has any insight into what this class is I'd really appreciate it.
I can't find anything concrete online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a generated class with some kind of CSS tool or frameworks like styled-components, Emotion or PostCSS.

Comment: Hey Dmytro :) Yeah I figured as much too, but I'm trying to find out where/how its used

Comment: Hey, I think it is randomly generated by this online service https://www.hubspot.com/email-signature-generator My guess is that they use these classes to transfer inline CSS like this class="sc-jlyJG bbyJzT" style="text-decoration: none; color: rgb(79, 47, 22); font-size: 12px;"